# Join enums in java

Tags: java

I have these enums :

```
public interface MyEnum {
}

public enum Foo implements MyEnum{
    A("Foo_a"),
    B("Foo_b"),
    C("Foo_c")

    private String name = "";
    Foo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public enum Bar implements MyEnum {
    A("Bar_a"),
    B("Bar_b"),
    C("Bar_c")
    private String name = "";
    Bar(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I would have to use a method to join my enums like this :

```
join(Foo, A, B)
```

or otherwise (and better) :

```
Foo.join(A, B)
```

that returns :

```
"Foo_a, Foo_b"
```

I tried this :

```
static String join(MyEnum table, Object ... words) {
    String joined = words[0].toString();
    for(int i = 1 ; i<words.length ; i++) {
        for(MyEnum.class t : MyEnum.values()) {
            if (t == words[i]) {
                joined += ", " + words[i].toString();
            }
        }   
    }
    return joined;
}
```

but it seems I can't do `for(MyEnum.class t : MyEnum.values())`.

Do you have any idea to implement this method ?

Comment: The interface `MyEnum` doesn't have a method named `values()`.

Comment: instead of `MyEnum.values()`, you probably meant `table.values()`

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve here? Would you like to be able to join elements from different enums? The simple answer from @Jesper seems to be all you need here. Please be more specific if it is not sufficient for you.

Comment: @Joffrey yes, I meant table.values().

Comment: The Jesper's solution works but if it possible I would like to don't specify "Foo.xxx" in each argument. In fact I would like to enumerate several database tables and do something like :
`query = "INSERT INTO Foo " + Foo.join(a, b, c) + " VALUES ..."`.

Comment: @user2914540 `table.values()` still won't work. `table` is of type `MyEnum`, which is an interface, not one of your enums, as you seem to expect it to be. If you want to loop through the values of one of your enums, you should do `Foo.values()`, or `Bar.values()`, to get their respective values. It would really help if you told us EXACTLY what you are trying to accomplish with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the parameter `table` anywhere in your method, you don't need to pass it. Also, why are you trying to loop over the enum values of `MyEnum` (which doesn't work, since interface `MyEnum` does not have a `values()` method)? You can just as well just loop over the `words` array.

This simple version works with any kind of object, including your enum values:

```
static String join(Object... words) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (words.length > 0) {
        sb.append(words[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
            sb.append(", ").append(words[i].toString());
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really just guess, but I think what you want to do is to join the enums into a single string representation. so from List of enums

```
[Foo.A, Foo.B, Bar.B]
```

you want to create string

```
"Foo_a, Foo_b, Bar_b"
```

If this is the case, you need to have common method in the interface, which will provide the names:

```
public interface MyEnum {
    String getName();
}
```

Also your enums must implement this method and return its name in it

```
public enum Foo implements MyEnum{
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And then you can have your join method:

```
static String join(MyEnum... words) {
    if(words == null || words.length == 0){
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder joined = new StringBuilder(words[0].getName());
    for(int i = 1 ; i<words.length ; i++) {        
            joined.append(", ").append(words[i].getName());
    }
    return joined.toString();
}
```

Comment: In his case, the interface method would be `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However will not join enums of several type, ie `[Foo.a, Foo.b]` or `[Bar.a, Bar.b]` but never `[Foo.a, Bar.a]`. I just want to know if it's possible to specify the enum type in my join method to don't specify it on each argument.

Comment: Sure, but then he doesn't need the interface at all. It may/may not be an abuse of toString(), depending if name should be the string representation of the object.

Comment: If you will not mix types, you don't need an interface. When you want to join the results of toString(), then use "Object... " as the argument type, when you want to get something more specific from your enum, use the enum type.